# Use Thymeleaf variable in React

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is there a way to use a Thymeleaf variable in React?

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510634/how-to-use-thymeleaf-thtext-in-reactjs) that this is supposed to be a bad idea. The problem is, that I created a Spring Boot application with Thymeleaf, that incorporates a login mechanism. I got the Spring Boot Thymeleaf example from the security part (Part 5 - Securing the UI and the API) [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/).

I use Basic for authenticating with username/password. At the top of the `<body>` element a "Hello, Username" `<div>` displays the logged in user and a logout-button.

What I need is the username value, i.e. "greg". It is located in the Thymeleaf variable `${#authentication.name}`. I would like to get that value and make use of it inside the React application bundled in `built/bundle.js`.

Is there any way to get the variable into React, i.e. set a globally accessible variable?

This is the `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Hello, <span id="managername" th:text="${#authentication.name}">user</span>.
        <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Log Out"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div th:with="message=${#authentication.name}"></div>

    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="built/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```